How did I solve the Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' error at flutter?
How did I solve the Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' error at flutter ?



I opened edit schemes in xcode and set the build configuration in debug mode and the problem was solved.
Make sure that debug mode is selected in the window that opens by selecting the edit scheme option under the runner in Xcode.

On stackoverflow,  you are welcome to answer your own questions, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. However, the answer should be posted as a reply to your question. That way,  you can accept your own answer after 48 hours and it will be marked with a green tick.
